# ASP.net MVC 5 EF6 Error While updating the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am quite new to **Asp.net MVC 5 EF6**. I am developing the application for Contoso Unversity which is provided by Microsoft on asp.net website. In chapter no.11 ***Implementing the Inheritance*** after adding the inheritance and adding the migration through migration command it worked but when i tried to apply the update-database command to the PMC, I faced this error:

> Error Number:15248,State:1,Class:11 Either the parameter @objname is
>   ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.

This is the code of My /inheritance migration class.
please guide me to a fix.

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class Inheritance : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            // Drop foreign keys and indexes that point to tables we're going to drop.
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Enrollment", "StudentID", "dbo.Student");
            DropIndex("dbo.Enrollment", new[] { "StudentID" });

            RenameTable(name: "dbo.Instructor", newName: "Person");
            AddColumn("dbo.Person", "EnrollmentDate", c => c.DateTime());
            AddColumn("dbo.Person", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128, defaultValue: "Instructor"));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Person", "HireDate", c => c.DateTime());
            AddColumn("dbo.Person", "OldId", c => c.Int(nullable: true));

            // Copy existing Student data into new Person table.
            Sql("INSERT INTO dbo.Person (LastName, FirstName, HireDate, EnrollmentDate, Discriminator, OldId) SELECT LastName, FirstName, null AS HireDate, EnrollmentDate, 'Student' AS Discriminator, ID AS OldId FROM dbo.Student");

            // Fix up existing relationships to match new PK's.
            Sql("UPDATE dbo.Enrollment SET StudentId = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Person WHERE OldId = Enrollment.StudentId AND Discriminator = 'Student')");

            // Remove temporary key
            DropColumn("dbo.Person", "OldId");

            DropTable("dbo.Student");

            // Re-create foreign keys and indexes pointing to new table.
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Enrollment", "StudentID", "dbo.Person", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
            CreateIndex("dbo.Enrollment", "StudentID");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Student",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
                        FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
                        EnrollmentDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

            AlterColumn("dbo.Person", "HireDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
            DropColumn("dbo.Person", "Discriminator");
            DropColumn("dbo.Person", "EnrollmentDate");
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.Person", newName: "Instructor");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:
1. Deleting all Migration files in your Migrations folder
2. Renaming your database in the connection string
3. Running PM> add-migration 
4. Running PM> update-database